# 'Flagging' duplicates without privileges.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicates

I don't yet have access to mark a question off-topic or duplicate, but as an active member I do come across questions which fall into these categories. I was wondering how without being able to vote as a duplicate should I express that it is a duplicate, should I just provide a link and let someone with correct access, pick it up and deal with it?

And for off-topic questions should I just mark them down.

It would be nice if there was a 'flag' feature for these posts that you have access to before being able to mark them. I just commented on one post in particular that was asked by the same person for a second time in about a week because the first one presumably had no suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

The flag link on the question should offer some selections around reasons to close, including as duplicate. These should appear in the queue for moderators and, if I recall correctly, in the queue for high rep users as well to agree or dispute (as well as vote appropriately).

That option is there for those without sufficient rep to vote.

Comment: Yes, using the flag link will put it in the review queue for anyone who has sufficient privileges to take action on the flag, so high rep users will be prompted to check if it should be closed.  For certain flag types (such as spam) it is actually possible for enough flags to cause action to be taken by the system without a high rep user or mod being involved as well.

Comment: @AJHenderson - Thanks, I wasn't sure. I'm either too low a rep on other sites or I'm a mod, so what I can see for these is at extremes.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that flagging requires 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That's the tool to use, the Flag -link. It will take the issue to mods' attention, and also to the review queue for higher rep users to vote on. Mods may act quickly on serious or otherwise very clear issues, but the normal case would be that review queue handles it.

You can try clicking the Flag-link. It won't raise any flag immediately, but a window opens to let you choose what is the matter there. So you can explore what is there. (Just click "Cancel" afterwards if it was just a curiousity call;)

Comment: Note that your screen will look a little different as you won't have close as an option.  Also, flagging does require 15 reputation.

Comment: Well, after 250 rep points you'll see it in your own questions, not before, like I thought.